# Is there a unique homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a finite field of order $q$ and $L$ be a finite extension of $K$.

Suppose $\tau$ : $L^{\times} \longrightarrow K^{\times}$ is a homomorphism for which $\tau (a) \tau (b) = \tau(ab)$ for all nonzero $a,b \in L^{\times}$.

Is it true $\tau = N_{L/K}$? ($N_{L/K}$ means a field norm).
If not, how can I represent $\tau$? What is a $\tau(x) = ?$ 
How can I compute $\tau$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$L^{\times}$ is a cyclic group. You can map a generator of it to any element of $K^{\times}$ and extend to a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

When you say $\tau \colon L^\times \to K^\times$ is a homomorphism, you're defining a group homomorphism from the multiplicative group $L^\times$ to the multiplicative group $K^\times$. By definition, these are all the non-zero elements of $L$ and $K$ respectively, and $\tau(a) \tau(b) = \tau(ab)$. These need not be mentioned (for you seem to be saying *this particular* $\tau$ is a homomorphism with these properties).

Since $K$ and $L$ are finite fields, $K^\times$ and $L^\times$ are cyclic groups (of order $|K| - 1$ and $|L| - 1$ respectively). In general, there are several homomorphisms between cyclic groups, so $\tau$ is not unique.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.